# Responsive content into responsive webpage

Tags: responsive-design, wordpress-theming, adsense

I have no experience coding responsive web, but I would like to add piece of responsive content into already responsive wordpress theme.

I would like to make two boxes in one line, one with adsense unit and the other one with post thumbnail and button.

This works, but I guess it's not exactly clean way.

```
<div style="width:100%;min-height:230px">

<div style="width:50%;float:left;min-width:230px">
adsense here
</div>

<div style="width:50%;float:left;text-align:center;min-width:230px" id='playGameButton'>
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?><br />
<a href='#' class='big-button bigblue'>Play Game</a>
</div>

</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What do you want help with? You say it works. If you mean not have inline style, then you need to edit the style.css file for the theme you're using and add your above inine style to a class and use the class name in the above HTML. Backup the original file first. And bare in mind default theme updates can remove changes you make to them. Look on Wordpress codex about making themes.

Comment: I was just looking for some more clever way how to do the same thing, but if it's ok like this, then my question is already answered. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Well "ok" is subjective. I would code it into the theme's external stylesheet with classes (or IDs if only used once) (but then I'd have made my own or client's theme from scratch anyway). Again, bare in mind if you have used the default theme you could lose the above method, and if you put it in the style.css, if the theme is updated. Wordpress Codex has all the answers for Wordpress stuffs (bit of sifting to do usually, tho)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. You can add a media query to make it more responsive as well.

```
<div class="cell leftside">
adsense here
</div>

<div class="cell rightside">
&lt;?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?&gt;<br />
<a href='#' class='big-button bigblue'>Play Game</a>
</div>
```

.table{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    min-height:230px;
    margin:0;
  }

.cell {
    vertical-align: top;
    display:table-cell;
    width:50%;
    min-width:230px;
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
  }

.rightside{
    background-color:#9baa32;
  }
  .leftside{
    background-color:#f37820;
  }

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .table{
      display:block;
    }

```
.cell {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  min-height:230px;
}
```

}

JSBin

http://jsbin.com/tezora/3/